# How do elemental weapons interact with Sword Magic?

Tags: bravely-default

I recently acquired the "Trident" weapon that says "Weapon attacks deal lightning damage." If I use the Spell Fencer's Sword Magic abilities to apply, let's say, Fire to the weapon, will the weapon deal Fire or Lightning damage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sword magic overrides the weapon's natural affinity you can test this by using a Flametongue against an enemy that gets healed by fire such as salamander. If attacked naturally (with out sword magic) the attack will heal the enemy, but if you use any ice sword magic first the attack now hits its weakness  instead.

To prove that it removes assets use Excalibur against demons. Normally the weapon deals bonus damage due to its light affinity but cast lightning sword magic (had done this on my auto battle to deal w/ the knights in Eternian central command) and you now do neutral damage to them despite using a weapon that would otherwise be effective against them